# LDAP filter - List all the users in a specific OU

Tags: filter, ldap

I need to display all the users in a specific OU.

I used the below filter, but it doesn't work.

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(ou=_Dorset,dc=andy,dc=com))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To display all the entries subordinate to `ou=_dorset`, transmit a search request to the server with the following parameters:

- base object: `ou=_Dorset,dc=andy,dc=com`
- search scope: subtree
- filter: `(objectCategory=user)`
- the list of attributes to retrieve

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you put the corrected filter query.